# Calculate time differences between multiple rows over unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data that looks like the following:

```
ID          EventDateTime
1656891     2015-04-21 23:54:36.443
1656891     2015-04-22 00:28:01.313
1656891     2015-04-23 16:09:55.440
1656891     2015-04-26 19:17:30.140
1656891     2015-04-26 21:50:45.167
1668876     2015-04-23 13:28:27.827
1668876     2015-04-23 15:57:15.393
1718737     2015-04-16 11:27:17.143
1743848     2015-04-16 03:15:50.900
1743848     2015-04-16 11:28:09.383
1743848     2015-04-21 17:32:47.610
1743848     2015-04-22 01:06:22.707
1746479     2015-04-16 18:36:26.587
1746479     2015-04-18 16:04:12.410
1746479     2015-04-20 21:01:50.907
1746479     2015-04-20 23:26:56.743
```

I need to `SELECT` the `DATEDIFF(MINUTE...)` on the `EventDateTime` column for a given `ID`.  For example, for `1656891` I should get `7076`.  Is there a way to calculate this for every `ID` such that I would get an output like:

```
ID         Minutes
1656891    7076
...        ...
```

I found some other posts about iteration, but the query ended up taking over a minute to run, so my code is obviously pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want the difference in minutes between the earliest and latest values for each id.  This is at least in the ballpark for the value 7076.

```
select id, datediff(minute, min(eventdatetime), max(eventdatetime) ) as minutes
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: That is substantially simpler.  Thank you ^_^